# inner join with group by

Tags: sql, function, sum

there are projects for every branch and every project have item_cost & outlay_fees

[all projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqyjj.png)

[item_cost for every project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eHXi.png)

[outlay_fees for every project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAMxe.png)

i need to calculate sum ( outlay_fees & item_cost )for every project
and i use this :

```html
SELECT
projects.project_no ,
projects.project_address ,
branch.branchName , 
sum(projectwork.item_cost) as totalcost ,
SUM(projectoutlay.projectOutlay_fess) as totalfees 
FROM projects 
INNER JOIN
branch on projects.branch_id = branch.branch_id 
JOIN
projectwork on projectwork.project_id = projects.projects_id 
JOIN
projectoutlay ON projectoutlay.project_id = projects.projects_id
GROUP BY projects.project_no;
```

but the result wrong calculation

[the results : total Cost & total fees is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ywp.png)

Comment: It's likely just a JOIN issue.  Reduce the SQL to review a single project to simplify the data you need to read.  Now start with one join at a time.  Look at and understand the result.  You'll find that either `branch` and/or `projectwork` and/or `projectoutlay` have multiple rows per project, which cause multiplication of rows from the other tables, which you didn't expect.  Calculate an aggregate per project for each table separately, then join those results.  You can use derived tables or CTE terms.  Give it a try and update the question with your attempt.

Comment: On another note: What's the difference between `project_no` and `project_id`?  You're grouping by `project_no`, but joining on `project_id`.  Is `project_no` and `project_id` unique in the `projects` table?

Comment: project_no like name of project and to be repeated later ..... project_id is ( primary key <auto increment> unique  )

Comment: Is that name unique also?  I'm just curious.  Provide structure, data and the expected result, if you're still stuck.

Comment: yes ... name is unique

Comment: @JonArmstrong All tables are loaded .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 With cte as(
 
 SELECT projectwork.project_id, 
           sum(projectwork.item_cost) as totalcost ,
           SUM(projectoutlay.projectOutlay_fess) as totalfees 
 FROM projectwork INNER JOIN projectoutlay
 ON projectwork.project_id = projectoutlay.projects_id 
 group by
     projectwork.project_id  
 )
 
 SELECT
      projects.project_no ,
      projects.project_address ,
      projects.branch_id,
      cte.totalcost,
      cte.totalfees
From project left JOIN cte
ON projects.project_no = cte.project_id
```

Comment: the problem in my sql code calculate sum (projectwork.item_cost)  & sum (projectoutlay.projectOutlay_fess) and multiply them

Comment: The result of the code ( totalcoast & totalfees ) is null